# Chrome debugger - How to use JS CPU profile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I want to use chrome debugger for JavaScript performance.
I use the `chrome debugger` to record the `JavaScript CPU profile`.
 Then, I got the record graph below: [image]

And each function will show me the detail about cost time, like that:
[image]

My questions are:

Q1: what is the mean of **Self Time** and **Total time**?

Q2: Why the count of **Self
    time** is not equal to **Total time**?

Q3:If I want to improve the perf about
    this code, may I just need to care about highly **Self
    time** function?

BTW, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127671/difference-between-self-and-total-in-chrome-cpu-profile-of-js) is not same for mine. Because, I have Q3 and that question is choose the heavy model to see the CPU profile but I choose the chart. So I want to know whether they are the same mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'self' and 'total' in Chrome CPU Profile of JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127671/difference-between-self-and-total-in-chrome-cpu-profile-of-js)

Comment: I think the question is not duplicator. Because, I have Q3.